# read the text of a file between 2 words in python

Tags: python, xml, search, keyword, text-extraction

I am trying to open, read and extract the content (fragment) that is between 2 words (which are opening and closing profile, also included) of an .xml locating the fragment by means of a keyword that I introduce and write only that fragment (between 2 tags) in another new .xml that I generate.

Currently the python script that I have allows me to open, read the source .xml file, search for the keyword that I introduce in the text and return those complete lines where the keyword is found by writing them in a new .xml file that I generate as follows:

```
keyword = 'Georgia'
occurrences = []
with open('test_input.xml') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        if keyword in line:
            occurrences.append(line)

archi1=open("test_output.xml","w") 
archi1.write(''.join(occurrences))
archi1.close()
```

The result I get is a "test_output.xml" file that contains the following:

```
     <id>Georgia-1</id>
         <profile>Georgia-p1</profile>
     <id>Georgia-2</id>
         <profile>Georgia-p2</profile>
```

And the problem is that I not only need it to return the complete lines that contain the keyword (in this case 'Georgia') but also the entire fragment that contains those two words and that is delimited between the opening and the closing of the word or tag 'profile', that is, I need it to return the following result:

```
<profile>
    <id>Georgia-1</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <profile>Georgia-p1</profile>
        <showtitle>Georgia_s1</showtitle>
        <ip>000.000.0.3</ip>
        <port>00003</port>
        <persistencePort>00033</persistencePort>
        <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
        <webstart.server.name>host_3</webstart.server.name>
        <codebaseProtocolServer>T3</codebaseProtocolServer>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>Georgia-2</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <profile>Georgia-p2</profile>
        <showtitle>Georgia_s2</showtitle>
        <ip>000.000.0.4</ip>
        <port>00004</port>
        <persistencePort>00044</persistencePort>
        <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
        <webstart.server.name>host_4</webstart.server.name>
        <codebaseProtocolServer>T4</codebaseProtocolServer>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

The full source .xml I am using is as follows:

```
<project>       

    
<profile>
    <id>Azerbaiyan-1</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <profile>Azerbaiyan-p1</profile>
        <showtitle>Azerbaiyan_s1</showtitle>
        <ip>000.000.0.1</ip>
        <port>00001</port>
        <persistencePort>00011</persistencePort>
        <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
        <webstart.server.name>host_1</webstart.server.name>
        <codebaseProtocolServer>T1</codebaseProtocolServer>
    </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>Azerbaiyan-2</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <profile>Azerbaiyan-p2</profile>
        <showtitle>Azerbaiyan_s2</showtitle>
        <ip>000.000.0.2</ip>
        <port>00002</port>
        <persistencePort>00022</persistencePort>
        <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
        <webstart.server.name>host_2</webstart.server.name>
        <codebaseProtocolServer>T2</codebaseProtocolServer>
    </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>Georgia-1</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <profile>Georgia-p1</profile>
        <showtitle>Georgia_s1</showtitle>
        <ip>000.000.0.3</ip>
        <port>00003</port>
        <persistencePort>00033</persistencePort>
        <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
        <webstart.server.name>host_3</webstart.server.name>
        <codebaseProtocolServer>T3</codebaseProtocolServer>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>Georgia-2</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <profile>Georgia-p2</profile>
        <showtitle>Georgia_s2</showtitle>
        <ip>000.000.0.4</ip>
        <port>00004</port>
        <persistencePort>00044</persistencePort>
        <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
        <webstart.server.name>host_4</webstart.server.name>
        <codebaseProtocolServer>T4</codebaseProtocolServer>
    </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>USA-1</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <profile>USA-p1</profile>
        <showtitle>USA1_s1</showtitle>
        <ip>000.000.0.5</ip>
        <port>00005</port>
        <persistencePort>00055</persistencePort>
        <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
        <webstart.server.name>host_5</webstart.server.name>
        <codebaseProtocolServer>T5</codebaseProtocolServer>
    </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>USA-2</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <profile>USA-p2</profile>
        <showtitle>USA1_s2</showtitle>
        <ip>000.000.0.6</ip>
        <port>00006</port>
        <persistencePort>00066</persistencePort>
        <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
        <webstart.server.name>host_6</webstart.server.name>
        <codebaseProtocolServer>T6</codebaseProtocolServer>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the input as XML and capture the `profile` elements that have an `id` child element whose text value contains the string "Georgia".

The following program uses the [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) standard library and outputs the wanted result:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")

# Iterate over all 'profile' elements
for profile in tree.findall("profile"):
    id = profile.find("id").text
    if "Georgia" in id:
        print(ET.tostring(profile).decode())
```

Comment: hello @mzjn, thank you very much for your help! i was really stuck with this problem... your solution is perfect!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: xml.etree.ElementTree has some incompatibility with certain tags of an xml? I have tried with another larger file that I have and the output does not return anything but I have tried to eliminate some different labels from the header and the end of the file and it already works... it's strange, isn't it?

Comment: You have accepted this answer. If you need more help, please ask a new question.